# How do I convert a 12-bit integer to a hexadecimal string in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert a number between 0 and 4096 ( 12-bits ) to its 3 character hexadecimal string representation in C#.

Example:

```
2748 to "ABC"
```

Comment: Is this a code problem or assignment OR are you simply trying to cross this hurdle? For the latter String.Format with some magic incantation gets the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
2748.ToString("X")
```

Comment: Note that if your integer is less than or equal to 255, you won't get 3 characters out of this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want exactly 3 characters and are sure the number is in range, use:

```
i.ToString("X3")
```

If you aren't sure if the number is in range, this will give you more than 3 digits.  You could do something like:

```
(i % 0x1000).ToString("X3")
```

Use a lower case "x3" if you want lower-case letters.

Comment: % is a pretty expensive operation.  (i & 0x0FFF).ToString("X3") is functionally similar, and much faster (although I would hope the compiler produces the same code either way)

Answer (score 1):

Note: This assumes that you're using a custom, 12-bit representation. If you're just using an int/uint, then Muxa's solution is the best.

Every four bits corresponds to a hexadecimal digit.

Therefore, just match the first four digits to a letter, then >> 4 the input, and repeat.

Comment: 2748.ToString("X") results in "ABC" not "0ABC"

Answer (score 1):

The easy C solution may be adaptable:

```
char hexCharacters[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
void toHex(char * outputString, long input)
{
   outputString[0] = hexCharacters[(input >> 8) & 0x0F];
   outputString[1] = hexCharacters[(input >> 4) & 0x0F];
   outputString[2] = hexCharacters[input & 0x0F];
}
```

You could also do it in a loop, but this is pretty straightforward, and loop has pretty high overhead for only three conversions.

I expect C# has a library function of some sort for this sort of thing, though.  You could even use sprintf in C, and I'm sure C# has an analog to this functionality.

-Adam

Comment: Sorry, this is a C# specific question, Thanks anyways.

Comment: Well, the thing is, Justin Tanner, he showed the algorithm perfectly.